# Determine the image of $\arg(z)= \alpha$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be a complex function defined by $f(z)=\frac1z$. I have to find the image of $\arg(z)= \alpha$ under $f$.

I don't know how to solve this problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\arg(z)=\alpha$ is the equation of a line that goes through the origin and makes an angle $\alpha$  with the $x$ axis. Now if $z=re^{i\alpha}$ then $1/z=r^{-1}e^{-i\alpha}$ and so $\arg{1/z}=-\alpha$. So the image is the line that goes through the origin and makes an angle $-\alpha$ with the $x$ axis.

Comment: why can we say arg(z)=$ \alpha $ is the equation of a line that goes through the origin?

Comment: I think I know why, because we have a point z and the slope $ \alpha$

Comment: In the Argand plane, a vector $z$ that makes a constant angle $\alpha$ with the $x$ axis is... colinear with the line that makes an angle $\alpha$ with the $x$ axis. The way you see it is right as well.

Answer (score -1):

$$
\frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{z}} \left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = \frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{z} z}
$$

$$
\text{Re}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = \frac{x} {\bar{z}{z}}, \qquad \text{Im }\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)= -\frac{i y}{\bar{z}z}
$$

Given the point $z = x + i y$, the Argument of $1/z$ is
$$
Arg \left( \frac{1}{z} \right) = \arctan \frac{\text{I'm}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}{\text{Re}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}
$$

Comment: is this  a hint? if it is, I don't see how to continue